# Case expression in a parameter list?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have two calls to a stored procedure with different parameters depending on an if statement. Is there a way to put a case expression in front of a parameter to include/not include based on that case instead of using an if statement and two different calls?

Here is my current code:

```
if (@SubmissionStatus = 'REJ' or @SubmissionStatus = 'ACP') and (@LoadUsage = '|CreateBatch|')
    begin
        --when current submission is 'OPT' we change it to 'REJ' before creating a new 'CRT' submission
        exec @internal = ii_UpdateClaimSubmission
        @Usage                          = @LoadUsage,
        @UserId                         = @UserId,
        @ClaimSubmissionId              = @OldClaimSubmissionId,
        @SubmissionStatus               = @OldSubmissionStatus,
        --@ExternalBatchNumber          = @ExternalBatchNumber,
        --@FrequencyType                = @FrequencyType,
        @ProcessingStatus               = @ProcessingStatus,
        @TechnicalErrorCode             = @RejectReasonCode,
        @TechnicalErrorDescription      = @RejectDescription,
        @TransactionAcknowledgementCode = @TransactionAcknowledgementCode,
        @ResubmissionNumber             = @ResubmissionNumber,
        @DoNotSendReason                = @DoNotSendReason,
        @DebugFlag                      = @DebugFlag,
        @InputAdjustmentVersion         = @Version,
        @ErrorMsg                       = @UserMsg out
    end
            else
                begin
                    -- we are updating an existing submission to potentially close it out, and not creating a new submission
                    exec @internal = ii_UpdateClaimSubmission
                                @Usage                          = @LoadUsage,
                                @UserId                         = @UserId,
                                @ClaimSubmissionId              = @OldClaimSubmissionId,
                                @ExternalBatchNumber            = @ExternalBatchNumber,
                                @FrequencyType                  = @FrequencyType,
                                @SubmissionStatus               = @SubmissionStatus,
                                @ProcessingStatus               = @ProcessingStatus,
                                @TechnicalErrorCode             = @RejectReasonCode,
                                @TechnicalErrorDescription      = @RejectDescription,
                                @TransactionAcknowledgementCode = @TransactionAcknowledgementCode,
                                @ResubmissionNumber             = @ResubmissionNumber,
                                @DoNotSendReason                = @DoNotSendReason,
                                @DebugFlag                      = @DebugFlag,
                                @ErrorMsg                       = @UserMsg out
```

In one parameter list I have extra parameters (@ExternalBatchNumber, @FrequencyType, @Version) and the other I don't.

Comment: tabs in code are the work of the devil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply pass NULL or another default value when the parameter is not required:

```
IF (@SubmissionStatus = 'REJ' or @SubmissionStatus = 'ACP') and (@LoadUsage = '|CreateBatch|')
BEGIN 
    SET @ExternalBatchNumber = null;
    SET @FrequencyType = null;
END;
```

Then you can simply use the second version of your call to `ii_UpdateClaimSubmission`.

Comment: For some reason it is saying 'incorrect syntax near 'CASE'' 
SSMS 17

Comment: I changed the answer to not use CASE WHEN at all. This is even easier.